# Can I Create an Array of Points Arrays in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net

`Dim myPointsArray As New List(Of Point)` creates an array that I can fill with a `For Next` loop but I have several separate arrays that I want to fill so it would be great if `Dim myPointsArrays(20) as`.... would work so that I don't have to Dim a points array for each of my separate arrays. Then I could fill them with a nested `For Next` loop.
This is me filling one array

```
For i = 1 To 6
myPointsArray.Add(New Point(Ox + HxPnt(4, i) / skale, Oy - HyPnt(4, i) / skale))
Next
```

Here Ox,Oy represent an origin, HxHyPnts are members of an array of points, skale is used to scale the global values to drawing with pixels.
Problem is that I need to draw lots of different polylines and polygons from dozens of arrays.

Comment: You have a `List(Of T)` (Generic List), not an array.  They are similar, but different.

Answer (score 2):

You can create nested lists (`List(Of T)` is not an `Array`):

```
Dim myPointsArray As New List(Of List(Of Point))
For i = 1 To 6
    Dim innerList = new List(Of Point)
    myPointsArray.Add(innerList)
    For j = 1 to 10
        innerList.Add(New Point(Ox + HxPnt(4, i) / skale, Oy - HyPnt(4, i) / skale))
    Next
Next
```

To iterate again over these values use the following:

```
For Each list As List(Of Point) in myPointsArray
    For Each p As Point in list
        // Access p here
    Next 
Next
```

Comment: Okay, I wrote this code and the compiler was ok with it, but I wasn't able to make it work in the form.paint event to use the drawlines graphics method.For i = 1 To 4
            Dim innerList = New List(Of Point)
            myPointsArray.Add(innerList)
            For j = 1 To HCnt(i)
                innerList.Add(New Point(Ox + HxPnt(i, j) / skale, Oy - HyPnt(i, j) / skale))
            Next
        Next

Comment: Me again..I need to be able to call these lists in form.paint , e.drawlines graphics. 
                innerList.Add(New Point(Ox + HxPnt(i, j) / skale, Oy - HyPnt(i, j) / skale))
So it looks like I can create these nested lists “xy points j of i arrays” but I need to use them as arrays of points that I can call separately or sequentially in the in the form.paint event. For example
For i = 1 to 4
e.graphics.drawlines(e.Graphics.DrawLines(myPen, myPointsArray.ToArray()).
Next i
Where does the “i” go? If this is to work.
In VB5 I used the polyline function in the Win32 API. That was easy.

Comment: Still stuck. In a button sub that then does a me.refresh to the form.paint event I fill the lists of lists with existing variables. Seems to work ok. Then.. in the form1.paint I wrote: For Each list As List(Of Point) In myPointsArray
                For Each p As Point In list
                     e.Graphics.DrawLines(myPen, myPointsArray.ToArray())
                Next
            Next.         but this doesn't work.        P.S. I wish I could format my queries with more characters, different fonts and carriage returns but it only lets me type this running string.

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `e.Graphics.DrawLines(myPen, myPointsArray.ToArray())` you're asking the Grpahics object to draw lines based on a List(List Of Point). You can just pass it the innerlist. If you want all points, you don't need nested lists. Just build one array and pass that to that function. Either way, this is a whole different question. Please create a separate question for this and reference it here if you want me to have a look.

Comment: Kenneth. Thanks for trying to help. If you look at my original question I hope you can see that I'm trying (for example) to draw 20 separate polylines of various numbers of points without having to declare and fill 20 separate points arrays and code 20 separate instances of e.graphics.drawpolyline. I tried working with the lists and got to the p.x and p.y values but VB will let me iterate them to fill an array but then wont let me call that array as a point() array.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
I created a new points array variable (newPoints), filled it from the list then converted it with the .ToArray thingy. Then drew each polyline in the loop by filling, clearing and refilling the array. Is this the best way to do this. Seems good to me.

```
For Each list As List(Of Point) In myPointsArray
   For Each p As Point In list
      newPoints.Add(New Point((Ox + p.X) / skale, (Oy + p.Y) / skale))
   Next
e.Graphics.DrawLines(myPen, newPoints.ToArray)
newPoints.Clear()
Next
```

Comment: Kenneth. See my answer above. I figured it out. Thanks for putting me on the track.